# JQuery append many many elements is made in one shot

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using jquery to append rows in a table.
I'm appending rows in an angular.forEach function in each loop but rows are rendered in my html page ine one shot : I mean the 1340 rows are displayed simultaneously insted of row by row.

I can not understand.
Here is an example of my code

```
angular.forEach(scope.contents, function(pack, indexPack) {
    var bodyTag = '<tbody>';

    if (pack.products.length > 0) {

        angular.forEach(pack.products, function(product, indexProduct) {
            bodyTag += '<tr>';
            angular.forEach(scope.headers, function(header, indexHeader) {
                var cellTag = '<td>';
                var cellClass= '';
                var cellContent = 'content 1';

                cellTag += cellContent+'</td>';
                bodyTag += cellTag;
            });
            bodyTag += '</tr>';
        });
    } else {
        bodyTag += '<tr>';
        angular.forEach(scope.headers, function(header, indexHeader) {
            var cellTag = '<td>';
            var cellClass= '';
            var cellContent = 'content 2';

            cellTag += cellContent+'</td>';
            bodyTag += cellTag;
        });
        bodyTag += '</tr>';
    }

    bodyTag += '</tbody>';
    $('#myTable').append(bodyTag);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Urgsss, this is really bad practise in angularJS. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat and make it rendered in your view.

Comment: The problem is that I have a very very long list and perfomances are too bad (16 seconds for displaying 2000 rows). I know that infinite scroll and paginations are alteratives but my company wants to display these 2000 rows so we are using jquery (time for displaying is now 3 seconds ...)

Comment: 2000 Items in a view is not a problem. Ive got above 10.000 in an application. Pushing stack by stack (200 Items at once) into the frontend works pretty fine. Take a look at this https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch and this https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not the core of my problem which is the render by jquery append method. The long list can (it depends on the use case) be displayed inside a fixed height diw which will always be in the viewport. So it cannot help me

Comment: Can't believe that. How do you display 2000 Items at once in a view Port? Lets say, one item = one row. One item = 1px height, so your viewport is minimum (X)*2000 height? For sure, your problem is jQuery here.

Comment: I don't want to display them at once actually. I would like to display one by one at each loop. Maybe I don't understand the viewport notion but what I would want is that jquery append method renders at each loop

Comment: Why? This question is "JQuery append many many elements is made in one shot". What you want, "one shot" or "I dont want to display them at once actually"? Try my solution, as I said, i did that with >10k items.

Comment: What I want is to render row by row since I use append method in a loop. What I have is unique render. I have passed to much time to refactor with jquery, I can not rerefactor, time is too short

Comment: Row by row is exactly what angularJS does! Exactly this happens if you are focusing an JavaScript Object, which is scoped by "ng-repeat" and be "pushed" item by item by your backend. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp looks like you did not understand angularJS right now.

Comment: With ng-repeat I had 16 seconds before any rendering and this is not acceptable. I had ng-repeat inside ng-repaeat inside ng-repeat. My dodel is very large (many properties)

Comment: Did you pushed item by item by using  github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch and this github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce? Also nested element should be not problem.

Comment: No I didn't I will try the although it was not my initial request. But with bindonce the list will not be refreshed if there is any change in my model ?

Comment: Yes, use bindonce if there is no need to update data in real time. It depends on your application, but its a must have optimization. If your data is to complex, try to push the data with timeouts into your view.

Comment: I have tried only angular-viewport-watch and time is 13 seconds ... this will not help me. I had already tried bindonce and performances were not so  much better and I need the view to be refreshed ...